# How can I transfer an Azure DevOps project from one organization to another?

Tags: azure-devops

In my DevOps organization, I've created a project for a client with git repo assets, boards, pipelines, etc. I'd like to transfer the project ownership from my organization to my client's organization.

How can I do this?

It's easy enough to switch ownership for the entire organization under "Organization Settings." But that's not what I want. I am looking, however, for that same workflow (if it exists) for a single project. The project ultimately needs to show up in their Organization space instead of mine.

If this isn't as simple as switching organizational ownership, is the save data an option?

I [read here that I can save project data](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/save-project-data?view=azure-devops). But, there are no instructions on re-importing that data elsewhere.  Also, I get the impression that I'm not getting a full project.

After the project is transferred they need to be able to continue to use it as it functioned in my organizational space.

Comment: I am not 100% sure that there is an all-in-one move package. I know you can move the repo and export/import the pipelines. I would check if there are different components that you can try to export and import one by one like this: [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61227055/6135564) [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57621967/how-do-i-move-work-items-from-one-organization-to-another)

Answer (score 2):

I feel this [thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/is-it-possible-to-clone-or-migrate-a-azure-devops/1099877) with this answer is relevant

> There is no official document to support this function.
> We can use this extension [OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-1455028.OpsHubVisualStudioOnlineMigrationUtility) to migrate source code, work items.
> In addition, there are [Copy or clone work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/copy-clone-work-items?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) and [move git repositories between team projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/devops/repos/git/move-git-repos-between-team-projects?view=azure-devops) features.

Seems worth mentioning that, in addition to the above, [AzDO Boards migration tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/extensions/migrate-integrate?view=azure-devops) lists:
[Azure DevOps Migration Tools](https://nkdagility.github.io/azure-devops-migration-tools/) [[marketplace link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration)] as an expert tooling option.

Answer (score 1):

moving an entire project currently isn't possible, and I don't foresee it being implemented. The git repo you can download, and then upload which can have your build and deploy scripts/configuration but will require some tuning. This is because things like subscriptions may not exist in the target organization for deployments.

Trying to migrate the project boards and work items is not possible because there might be different (or even custom) work item types, layout, process (agile vs scrum in AzDOs project settings) and expecting Microsoft to be able to map those automatically is unrealistic. Also, things like users, iterations, and teams are additional items that require a lot of attention to migrating boards. There is a public API for boards and tasks that can be programmed against if you wish to do a migration.